# Azure Devops deploy docker image to ACR using deployment job

Tags: docker, azure-devops, azure, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to deploy a docker image to Azure Container Registry via an Azure Devops pipeline. Now this works fine when I run it with this script:

```
trigger:
- master

variables:
  # Container registry service connection established during pipeline creation
  dockerRegistryServiceConnection: 'some_id'
  imageRepository: 'worker'
  containerRegistry: 'microcontainerapptest.azurecr.io'
  dockerfilePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Dockerfile'
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'

  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build and push stage
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build and push an image to container registry
      inputs:
        command: buildAndPush
        repository: $(imageRepository)
        dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
        containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
        tags: |
          $(tag)
```

However, I want to actually use a deployment job so I can run the pipeline in different environments. Therefore I updated the .yml like this:

```
trigger:
- master

variables:
  # Container registry service connection established during pipeline creation
  dockerRegistryServiceConnection: 'some_id'
  imageRepository: 'worker'
  containerRegistry: 'microcontainerapptest.azurecr.io'
  dockerfilePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Dockerfile'
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'

  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build and push stage
  jobs:
  - deployment:
    displayName: Build docker image
    environment: $(DEPLOY_ENVIRONMENT)
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: Docker@2
            displayName: Build and push an image to container registry
            inputs:
              command: buildAndPush
              repository: $(imageRepository)
              dockerfile: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Dockerfile
              containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
              tags: |
                $(tag)
```

Making a deployment job out of this. Now when I run the pipeline like this I get an error

> Unhandled: No Dockerfile matching  /home/vsts/work/1/s/Dockerfile  was found.

So it seems like the dockerfilePath is not valid anymore when I run it as a deployment job. I have searched but don't have a clue as to why this would be the case, does anybody know the answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly check out your source code, [because](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/deployment-jobs?view=azure-devops):

> A deployment job doesn't automatically clone the source repo. You can checkout the source repo within your job with `checkout: self`. Deployment jobs only support one checkout step.

```
strategy:
  runOnce:
    deploy:
      steps:

      - checkout: self
      
      - task: Docker@2
        displayName: Build and push an image to container registry
        inputs:
          command: buildAndPush
          repository: $(imageRepository)
          dockerfile: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Dockerfile
          containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
          tags: |
            $(tag)
```